# AR.js text gets hidden by sphere below it

Tags: ar.js

I'm experimenting with AR.js. When I display an a-text above an a-sphere, depth sensing gets the order wrong when the two overlap. How can I fix this?

- Github: https://github.com/naokipeter/kzn-ar/blob/master/index.html
- Github Pages page: https://naokipeter.com/kzn-ar/
- Barcode Marker: [image: Barcode Marker]
- Screenshot 1: [image: Screenshot 1]
- Screenshot 2: [image: Screenshot 2]